# Delete session data after 2 min in php

Tags: php, session-variables, session-timeout, php-5.3, php-5.4

I'm newbie in php and I have a question. So for example I have in session array a variable call `game_url`:

```
$_SESSION['game_url'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

Is it possible to make a `$_SESSION['game_url'] = '';` after 2 min after it has set? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes

Comment: pls show us, what you tried and how you want to use it. Just from the scratch I'd recommand AJAX for that kind of stuff.

Comment: You can store current time in a session and when someone will check this after 2 minute, you just check the time difference and make it empty.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['game_url']))
{
    $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time();
    $_SESSION['game_url'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
}
if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 120)) 
{
    unset($_SESSION['game_url']);
    unset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']);
}
```

Comment: In theory this works, in practice I would avoid the key "LAST_ACTIVITY" since it does sound like something common enough to be overwritten by a framework/library.